# Changing ViewController Frame from another class - iOS

Tags: ios

I am trying to move SensorViewController frame from another viewcontroller, called DownViewController. I created a delegate object and trying to change the frame, but it is not changing.

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SensorsViewController.h"

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SensorsViewController  *sensorViewController;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize sensorViewController;
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    sensorViewController = [[SensorsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SensorsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

}
```

DownViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    //Assign new frame to your view
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
// the following part should change SensorViewController but, it is not!

    [[appDelegate sensorViewController].view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-260,1030,768)];
}

-(void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1030,768)];
}
```

Comment: Where is the `sensorViewController` property setup and is it `nil`?

Comment: sensorViewController property in DownControllerView?.. I set up sensorViewController property in AppDelegate

Comment: Show the code for the setup in `AppDelegate`. Have you debugged to check that happens?

Comment: please see updated AppDelegate.m code

Comment: Do you have another instance created anywhere. And what does debugging show the frame to be (before and after you change it)?

Comment: SensorsViewController class created with .h, .m, and xib

Comment: Where do you push/present/add the sensor view controller ?

Comment: I am not changing any viewcontroller, because I added freeform of DownViewController onto SensorViewController

Comment: Does it get better when you do `self.sensorViewController = [[SensorsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SensorsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];` instead?